# Floating 3 divs within a container div

Tags: css, html, spacing

I am attempting to float 3 divs within a container div. I thought it would be simple but I'm having difficulty keeping them evenly spread apart. As I want the website to be somewhat responsive, so I can't have the spacing specified in px.

CSS:

```
#circlecontain{background-color:green;height:200px; width:1200px; margin:auto;}

.circle{width:200px;height:200px;border-radius:100px; 
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#fff;
line-height:150px;text-align:center;background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
margin:auto; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;
 }
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold them inside 3 div elements with a width of `33%` each, and use `margin: auto;` on round divs, this way they will be equal.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zPaaD/)

```
<div class="wrap_me">
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap_me">
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap_me">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap_me {
    width: 33%;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    float: left;
}

.wrap_me div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: auto;
}
```

You can also hold this inside a single container with a `min-width` property so that your elements don't wrap incase of insufficient width

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting there, however the circles are not centering within the wrap divs. despite margin:auto

Comment: @user1944305 Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Nevermind, it had something to do with display:inline-block, just removed it and seems to be working ok. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

What Mr.Alien said isn't wrong, but

> I'm having difficulty keeping them evenly spread apart

If you have **three** divs you want to distribute even along the full width of the container, you can float the left-most div to the left, the right-most div to the right and the middle div will get `float:none` and `margin: auto`, like so:

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}

.container div {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.inner-left {
    float: left;
}

.inner-middle {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
}

.inner-right{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

See the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xkD8/1)**.

**EDIT**:
updated fiddle - didn't save...